# Why rancher taints the node with cattle.io/os=linux:NoSchedule by default

Tags: rancher, rancher-rke

From: https://ranchermanager.docs.rancher.com/v2.6/integrations-in-rancher/logging/taints-and-tolerations, it says:

"By default, Rancher taints all Linux nodes with cattle.io/os=linux, and does not taint Windows nodes. "

I wonder why rancher do this taints by default. To my understanding, users can do it by themself.
Although it gives the tolerations way to make pod scheduled on that node, I have to change the pod spec anyhow. I don't want to do that(change my yaml..).

I tried to remove the taints from that nodes on rancher webUI, but it is added back immediately after "Save".

How can I remove it. Also I want to know the background of rancher setting it.

rancher version: v2.6.5
k8s version: 1.22.17
cni type: flannel host-gw